# XML deserializing null properties to zero and false

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am passing an xml doc with some attributes missing to a deserilaliser. I need the missing values to be null in the resulting object but currently ints deserialise to zero and bools to false.

The example below shows a doc with vals deserialising correctly but the doc without vals returning the zeros and nulls.

How do force the deserialiser not to treat missing attributes like this.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SOQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var resultWithVals = getObject(docWithVals());
            var resultWithoutVals = getObject(docWithoutVals());

            Console.WriteLine("WITH VALS");
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithVals.someBool);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithVals.someFloat);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithVals.someInt);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithVals.someString);


            Console.WriteLine("WITHOUT VALS"); // nulls are returned here as zero and false
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithoutVals.someBool);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithoutVals.someFloat);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithoutVals.someInt);
            Console.WriteLine(resultWithoutVals.someString);

            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        public static XmlDocument docWithVals()
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Result"));
            el.SetAttribute("someString", "Hello World");
            el.SetAttribute("someBool", "true");
            el.SetAttribute("someInt", "1");
            el.SetAttribute("someFloat", "1.1");
            return doc;

        }

        public static XmlDocument docWithoutVals()
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Result"));
            el.SetAttribute("someString", "Hello World");
            return doc;

        }


        public static Result getObject(XmlDocument doc)
        {

                var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(new Result().GetType());
                var myStream = new MemoryStream();
                doc.Save(myStream);
                myStream.Position = 0;
                var r = mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
                return (Result)r;
         }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string someString { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool someBool { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int someInt { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public float someFloat { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DefaultValueAttribute` to provide your unintialised fields with a default value. In your case you could write

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;

[XmlAttribute, DefaultValue(true)]
public bool someBool { get; set; }
```

---

Edit. Please see the note on the MSND page [note on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx):

> A DefaultValueAttribute will **not** cause
>   a member to be automatically
>   initialized with the attribute's
>   value. You must set the initial value
>   in your code.

This issue has also been resolved in [XML serialization and DefaultValue("") related problem in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882164/xml-serialization-and-defaultvalue-related-problem-in-c-sharp). **So to set your default values, you must specify these in your code.**

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have looked at that. Nothing there seems to work for deserialising null attributes. Could you show me what specifically i am looking for in relation to my example. Thanks

Comment: This [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)] appears to work when serialising to xml but not deserialising from it.

Comment: This attribute has no affect when deserilising. I have tried [XmlAttribute, DefaultValue(null)] as well which also has no affect.

Comment: -1 Where in the question is `DefaultValueAttribute` mentioned?

Comment: Please reedit if you can as the current solution doesnt work. bool? casuses a reflection error in the serialiser and the docs say nullable types cannot be serialised.

Comment: I know this. I apologise. This is the same error I pointed out with D Stanley's solution below. However, these links and references should solve you issue. That is, you must set these defaults in code. All the best...

Answer (score 0):

`int`s and `float`s cannot have null values - their default values are `0` and `false`, respectively.

If they should be allowed to be null, change then to nullable types:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string someString { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool? someBool { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int? someInt { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public float? someFloat { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that anything using this type will now have to check for null values first using `HasValue` before using those fields and/or access the values with the `Value` property.

Comment: Making them nullable types will not help here as is stated in the docs. Infact, making them nullable means they become un-serializeble with the `XmlSerializer`!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ISerializable interface and use GetObjectData method.

Please check [Custom Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use something like this :

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool someBool { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool someBoolSpecified { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool? SomeBool
    {
        get
        {
            return someBoolSpecified ? someBool : default(bool?);
        }
        set
        {
            someBoolSpecified = value != default(bool?);
            someBool = value ?? default(bool);
        }
    }
```

As per the [`XmlSerializer` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) :

> Another option is to use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The pattern is created in the form of propertyNameSpecified. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName". This is shown in the following example.